# Can we talk about approximation when the decision problem for solution existence is NP-Hard

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-theory, combinatorial-optimization, hypergraph, approximation-algorithms

I am wishing to design an approximation algorithm for an optimization problem where the existence of solution for corresponding decision problem is not guaranteed. Is it wise to find an approximation algorithm by just assuming that if there exist  a solution? I didn't find any literature which says one should not try for approximation if there is no guarantee of existence of a solution.

Comment: Proceeding by trying to find a solution even if you have not been able to prove a priori it exists is a common practice in engineering and physics: said that, no one (not even a "purist") will say to you that this is forbidden. However, if your problem has implications in safety and reliability of a process, the result should be used with reasonable caution.

Comment: Can we consider this approach in theoretical aspects

Comment: Yes: this is definitively a branch of [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) so it is applicable to both theoretical and quantitative aspects of the problems at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to have been of some help. 